# Como acessar membro de outra classe?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um `JPanel` que contem todos os elementos gráficos, campos de textos botoes etc. Essa é uma classe diferente, que precisa saber todos os atributos da da JPanel. O problema é que não ta acessando o membro da classe `JPanel`, ja tentei declarar os componentes como public private e default

```
public class TrataEventosClass implements ActionListener {



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOU JUST CLICKED A BUTTON!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,txt1.getText()); // txt1 nao aparece mesmo sendo public na outra classe.
    }

}
```

Classe do painel

```
public class JPanelClass extends JPanel {

    JTextField txt1;

     JTextField txt2;

     JButton btn1;

     JButton btn2;



    JPanelClass(){

       this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
       iniciarElementos();
      // 
    }


    private void iniciarElementos(){

         txt1 = new JTextField(10);
         add(txt1);

         txt2 = new JTextField(10);
         add(txt2);

         btn1 = new JButton("Salvar");
         btn1.addActionListener(new TrataEventosClass());
         add(btn1);

         btn2 = new JButton("Limpar campos");
         add(btn2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Esse listerner está sendo aplicado ao JTextField que você ta tentando pegar o texto?

Comment: nao, ta sendo aplicado a um botao. q vai pegar o texto de todo formulario e salvar num txt.

Comment: Há necessidade de uma classe separada para listener realmente? Se vai aplicar só a um botão, eu não vejo necessidade alguma de criar uma nova classe para tratar o evento.

Comment: o problema é q to tentando fazer em outra classe. se eu dar um addActionListener(new ActionListener(){});, na mesma classe da certo, eu consigo ter acesso aos componentes e seus metodos. mas agora to tentando fazer o eventhandler ser outra classe. mas nao consigo acessar os metodos dos componentes...

Comment: Se for criar uma classe a parte de listener pra acessar um componente que ela nem está vinculada não é uma boa pratica em swing. O certo é somente a classe da tela ter acesso aos seus componentes, violar isso somente quando não tiver outro jeito por alguma exigencia de projeto, apesar que nunca vi essa necessidade. Você pode criar um getter na classe de painel para o jtexfield, o que é reinventar a roda na minha opiniao.

Comment: perfeito, é mais facil criar o ActionListener na mesma classe. eu pensei q nao era legal fazer isso, mas enfim. muito obrigado!

Comment: Se você quiser ter a classe a parte, ao inves de usar classe anonima, você faz uma inner class. Assim você mantem a mesma estrutura atual, mas a listener terá acesso aos componentes, pois ele também será parte da classe de tela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode conseguir esse acesso se transformar sua classe `TrataEventosClass` como uma classe interna de `JPanelClass`:

```
public class JPanelClass extends JPanel {

    JTextField txt1;

     JTextField txt2;

     JButton btn1;

     JButton btn2;



    JPanelClass(){

       this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
       iniciarElementos();
      // 
    }


    private void iniciarElementos(){

         txt1 = new JTextField(10);
         add(txt1);

         txt2 = new JTextField(10);
         add(txt2);

         btn1 = new JButton("Salvar");
         btn1.addActionListener(new TrataEventosClass());
         add(btn1);

         btn2 = new JButton("Limpar campos");
         add(btn2);

    }

    class TrataEventosClass implements ActionListener {



        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOU JUST CLICKED A BUTTON!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,txt1.getText()); // txt1 nao aparece mesmo sendo public na outra classe.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: otimo!. na sua opniao existe mercado pra swing hj em dia? to aprendendo por curiosidade. iniciei um curso de html5 e css3 pra futuramente usar Spring mvc, q todos dizem dominar o mercado.

Comment: @IgorAugusto existir existe, mas acredito que a tendencia agora seja tudo em nuvem. Aplicações desktop tendem a ficar no passado, ou em lojas virtuais(como no caso do windows 10, celulares, distribuições linux populares, etc). Aprender sempre vale a pena, mas pro mercado eu acho meio complicado.

Comment: @IgorAugusto caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado, você pode aceita-la clicando no `v` a esquerda para encerrar a questao como resolvida :)